# Emmision not working for Principled BSDF

Tags: materials, emission

I have an image texture of some windows(as you can see from the other objects in my file. When I plug in this image texture into the emission it does not work. I tried it with a cube and it worked. Im guessing my issue might have to do with my mesh but I have no clue what to do.

[image]

Comment: Do you have UVs on your windows? If not, the texture won't be visible as it has nothing to sit on

Comment: Thanks I cube projected it then it worked